# NMAP - Port 4111 XGRID?

Tags: nmap

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-04-24 10:19 BST
Stats: 0:00:27 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing Service Scan
Service scan Timing: About 0.00% done
Nmap scan report for local.domain.com (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.10s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
4111/tcp open  xgrid?
```

Hi,

I've been given an IP address and a port number (changed in example above) and a note about playing a game. I scan the port in question and get the above but I can neither NC or Telnet into it

Any advice?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Is this part of a security game (CTF)?  What do you mean you changed the port in the example.  Why?

Comment: The IP is changed in the example as it's our live system. It was a test set for us. Apparently the server is experiencing problems...

Comment: Your question isn't clear because you aren't asking any question... Are you concern about a performance issue, lag, disconnection, cannot connect to the service or do you wanna detect what service is ruining on this port ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a much more robust NMAP scan, look at the other ports as well, and try fingerprinting the services as well as the OS.

I'm guessing you did something like `nmap -p 4111 IPaddress`

First try adding the -sV flag

```
nmap -sV -p 4111 IPaddress
```

This will give you the version of the software running on that port using fingerprinting.